# Does the calorie count of these pistachio nuts include the shell?

Tags: nutrient-composition, calories

This pack of nuts states 600 calories per 100g.

Does this calorie count include the shell?

[image]

Comment: Have you worked out a way to eat the shell?

Comment: I think the question might be 100g of (nuts and shell) vs 100g of nuts. I would expect more calories in the latter, since we don't eat the shell.

Comment: @KateGregory The full USDA nutrition info says "Nutrient values and weights are for edible portion". It has 562 kcal/100g, though, bit of a discrepancy.

Comment: Hi Jefromi, This isn't in the jurisdiction of the USDA. Maybe I should have shown the complete image of the nutritional information, but I didn't think it was all relevant so I didn't. However, while I haven't worked out a way to eat the shell that doesn't mean that someone else hasn't either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, in most jurisdictions, the calories would be based on the edible portion (or the commonly eaten portion), so oranges without the peel, nuts without the shell.

Comment: In the case of most nut shells, it would be advantageous for an unscrupulous company to instruct its lab to include the shells. Since most of the nutrients, oils and other chemicals a plant needs to propagate are contained in the kernel, there would be less nutrients overall by weight if the lab chose to burn the whole nut instead of just the kernel. But that's just me being cynical.